# I need to change a python discord bot's avatar (profile picture) using discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

This is the code I have for changing the avatar so far:

```
with open("image.png", "rb") as file:
     await discord.ClientUser.edit(self=, avatar=file)
```

First, I don't even know if this is how you change a bot's profile picture. If this is the way, I don't know what I need to put after `self=`. I tried reading the docs and asking people how to do it but I didn't find anything to resolve this. Any help will be apreciated.

This is how I define my client: `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')`

Comment: Is this command inside a cog file?

Comment: @Nurqm no, it's inside a .py file which contains the rest of the bot's code.

Comment: @Cookie_Monster534 this comment is outdated but due to people still viewing this, I'd like to clarify that cogs are also just .py files but using the commands.Cog class :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ClientUser` to change the profile picture but you need to call the class. You can't do `discord.ClientUser.edit`. For changing the avatar, you need a [bytes like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object). So, this should work:

```py
with open('image.png', 'rb') as image:
    await client.user.edit(avatar=image)
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'edit'

Comment: Can you edit your question with the codeline that you define the `client`? And also, what is your prefix for commands?

Comment: I have already tried using `client.user.edit.(avatar=...)`. It gives me this error: `AttributeError: '_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute 'startswith`'

Comment: Using `client.edit(avatar=image)` gives me this error `AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'edit'` and this error `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'edit'`

Comment: Nvm I forgot that i needed to call the class. I will go do that

Comment: It's `TypeError: edit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Comment: Are you sure you're not using it in the cogs or using the same code in the answer?

Comment: What do I need to put in the class (I'm assuming that i need to put the code as a function) and how do I call the class after that. I'm struggling with the `self=`I'm not using the cogs. Also I'm using `discord.ClientUser.edit`

Comment: For defining the `ClientUser`, you need to do `client_user = discord.ClientUser(state=, data=)` but I have no idea what are the `state` and `data` parameters.

Comment: This is the whole relevant code 

`client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@client.command()
async def temp(ctx, temp_username: discord.Member):
    image_url = temp_username.avatar_url_as(format="png", size=1024)
    str(image_url)
    r = requests.get(image_url, stream=True)
    r.raw.decode_content = True
    with open(f'image_url.png', 'wb') as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
    print(image_url)
    with open("image_url.png", "rb") as image:
        await discord.ClientUser.edit(avatar=image)`

Comment: Don't do `await discord.ClientUser.edit`, do `client.user.edit`.

Comment: Doing it this way still gives me this error that I have no idea how to fix `TypeError: edit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Comment: What should `self=` equal?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. If the answer isn't helpful, you should remove the accepted answer mark.

Comment: It didn't solve the whole thing but it sure did help. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 3):

The above answer has the right idea but is missing something.

This is how to do it:

```
with open('image.png', 'rb') as image:
    await client.user.edit(avatar=image.read())
```